# Count number of rows where multiple criteria are met

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, conditional-statements, frequency

I'm trying to generate a table that shows a count of how many items are in any given status on any given day. My result table has a set of Dates down column A and column headers are various statuses. A sample of my data table with headers looks like this:

```
Product | Notice | Assigned | Complete | In Office | In Accounting 
   1    | 5/5/13 |  5/7/13  | 5/9/13   |  5/10/13  |    5/11/13 
   2    | 5/5/13 |  5/6/13  | 5/8/13   |  5/9/13   |    5/10/13
   3    | 5/6/13 |  5/9/13  | 5/10/13  |  5/10/13  |    5/10/13 
   4    | 5/4/13 |  5/5/13  | 5/7/13   |  5/8/13   |    5/9/13 
   5    | 5/7/13 |  5/8/13  | 5/10/13  |  5/11/13  |    5/11/13
```

If my output table were to contain a set of dates in the first column with the statuses as headers, I need a count of how many rows were at the given status and had not yet transitioned to the next status so that in the Notice column, I'd have a count of rows where the Notice Date was <= X AND where the Assigned, Complete, In Office, In Accounting are all greater than X.

I've used a `Sum(if(frequency(if` statement to get me REALLY close but I feel like I need to have an AND statement within the second IF like this `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(AND`

Here's what I have that won't work:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(AND(Table1[Assigned]<=A279,Table1[[Complete]:[In Accounting]]<=A279),ROW(Table1[[Complete]:[In Accounting]])),ROW(Table1[[Complete]:[In Accounting]]))>0,1))
```

If I take the "AND" portion out, this works fine except I need it to ONLY count rows where the given status actually has a date so if an "Assigned" date is empty, I don't want that row to be counted for the Assigned column.

Here's an example of what I'd expect to see in the results. I've listed the count in the each column as well as the corresponding product numbers in parenthesis. The corresponding product numbers are for reference only and won't actually be in the result table.

```
Date | Notice  | Assigned | Complete
 5/6 | 2 (1,3) | 2 (2,4)  |  0
 5/7 | 2 (3,5) | 2 (1,2)  |  1 (4)
 5/8 | 1 (3)   | 2 (1,5)  |  1 (2)
```

Comment: `My result table has a set of Dates down column A and column headers are various statuses.` I can see dates almost everywhere except column A. i see Product in Col A. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Table above isn't the example of the result table. That's the source data table. i'll edit to show a sample of the result table

Comment: @pnuts: Even I wanted to ask that question but then I saw OP's comment in the post ;) `the corresponding product numbers are for reference only and won't actually be in the result table.`

Comment: was a typo pnuts. I've corrected the count to accurately reflect counting product 2 and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, assuming you have the original data in A1:F6 then with 2nd table headers in B9:D9 and row labels in A10:A12 then you can use this "array formula" in B10

`=SUM((B$2:B$6<=$A10)*(MMULT((C$2:$F$6>$A10)+(C$2:$F$6=""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C$2:$F$6)^0))=COLUMNS(C$2:$F$6)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down and across (see screenshot below)

As you can see the results are as per your requirement. If you replace dates with blanks it will still work

`MMULT`is a way to get a single value from each row even when you are looking at multiple columns.

I used cell references because I think that's easier, especially when copying the formula across and having a reducing range.......but you can use structured references if you want

[image]

Comment: Wow. Very impressive solution. Works great! Thanks @barry-houdini

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using COUNTIFS to count based on multiple criteria. It is fairly well documented here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx (2007+ only)

Basically, you use it like

```
=COUNTIFS(first_range_to_check, value_you_want_in_first_range, ...)
```

where the ... represents as many pairs as you want (up to 127 total pairs), note the conditions are AND connection so if you have two pairs, the first pair AND the second pair must return true for that row to count.

Comment: When I tried this, it didn't work because countifs works like a giant "And" statement but what I need is an "OR" statement as far as the second portion goes so that it only counts a row if the corresponding status is the correct date but NOT if any of the later statuses occur on or before the same date.

Comment: That's still "AND". Col1<=Date AND Col2>Date AND Col3>Date AND Col4>Date. Do the various statuses occur in order? If so then it would be sufficient just to check that the next status only is > Date

Comment: They should, but occasionally they are blank therefore each column (status) needs to either be blank OR above the current date for that column to pass. So if Notice is 5/9 and Assigned is Blank and Complete is 5/12... the given product would NOT be counted as "Notice" on 5/12 but would on 5/11.

Comment: OK, that **would** be a little trickier for COUNTIFS to achieve - let me think about it.......